# Posting to a Facebook page on behalf of page using a Facebook application by anyone

Tags: facebook, post

I have a web page linked to a Facebook application where users can log in by their Facebook account.
I have also a Facebook page for my application where anybody can post.
What I'd like to achieve is the following:
- An ordinary user logs in to my web page using her Facebook account,
- She adds an information to my web page (for example a book name),
- That information is instantly posted to my application Facebook page under page's name (for example "this book is read by someone").
I don't want it to be posted by the user, I don't want it to be posted by myself (admin of the page).
I don't want to mention about the user, it will be anonymous information.
But I couldn't find a way to do it either as JS or PHP.
Any suggestion is welcome.
Many thanks.

Comment: You will need to get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to use access tokens but I couldn't succeed. As far as I understand, page access token is granted to a user who has admin rights for the Facebook page. But I want something to be posted on the Facebook page by that Facebook page when an ordinary user who doesn't any admin role has added some information to my web page. Can you please let me know how I can use access tokens for this purpose? Thank you...

Comment: _“But I want something to be posted on the Facebook page by that Facebook page”_ – and that’s why you’ll need a page access token. Get it, store it somewhere on your server – and then use it when making the API call to post what the user entered. If your general knowledge on how to use the API is close to none (and that’s what it looks like to me), then please start by reading the docs.

Comment: "Get it, store it somewhere on your server". Now it's clear. I couldn't think of getting an access token as the admin and re-use it for other users, too. Many thanks. My general knowledge has been increased by 100%!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Get it, store it somewhere on your server – and then use it when making the API call to post what the user entered.